# Query related to stemming in NLP

Tags: nlp, nltk, python-3.7, stemming

I am working on hands-on task based on stemming under NLP using python.

Below is the task which would required to be executed step wise to fetch the result.

I have completed till step 13 and got stuck at step number 14 and 15 (see below).

Please help me to know how to perform the step number 14 and 15.

#### TASK

1. Import the text corpus **brown**.
2. Extract the list of words associated with text collections belonging to the humor genre. Store the result in the variable **humor_words**.
3. Convert each word of the list humor_words into lower case, and store the result in **lc_humor_words**.
4. Find the list of unique words present in **lc_humor_words**. Store the result in **lc_humor_uniq_words**.
5. Import the corpus **words**.
6. Extract the list of words associated with the corpus words. Store the result in the variable **wordlist_words**.
7. Find the list of unique words present in **wordlist_words**. Store the result in **wordlist_uniq_words**.
8. Create an instance of PorterStemmer named, **porter**.
9. Create an instance of LancasterStemmer named, **lancaster**.
10. Stem each word present in **lc_humor_uniq_words** with porter instance, and store the result in the list **p_stemmed**
11. Stem each word present in **lc_humor_uniq_words** with lancaster instance, and store the result in the **listl_stemmed**`
12. Filter the stemmed words from **p_stemmed** which are also present in **wordlist_uniq_words**. Store the result in **p_stemmed_in_wordlist**.
13. Filter the stemmed words from **l_stemmed** which are also present in **wordlist_uniq_words**. Store the result in **l_stemmed_in_wordlist**.
14. Filter the words from **lc_humor_uniq_words** which have the same length as its corresponding stemmed word present in **p_stemmed**, and also contains at least one different character from the corresponding stemmed word. Store the result in the list **p_stemmed_diff**.
15. Filter the words from **lc_humor_uniq_words** which have the same length as its corresponding stemmed word, present in **l_stemmed**, and also contains at least one different character from the corresponding stemmed word. Store the result in list **l_stemmed_diff**.
16. Print the number of words present in **p_stemmed_diff**.
17. Print the number of words present in **l_stemmed_diff**.

-Below is the which I have completed till step 13.

```
import nltk

import nltk.corpus

from nltk.corpus import brown

humor_words = brown.words(categories = 'humor')

lc_humor_words = [w.lower() for w in humor_words]

lc_humor_uniq_words = set(lc_humor_words)

from nltk.corpus import words

wordlist_words = words.words()

wordlist_uniq_words = set(wordlist_words)

from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

porter = PorterStemmer()

from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer

lancaster = LancasterStemmer()

p_stemmed = []

for word in lc_humor_uniq_words:

    p_stemmed.append(porter.stem(word))

l_stemmed = []

for wordd in lc_humor_uniq_words:

    l_stemmed.append(lancaster.stem(wordd))

p_stemmed_in_wordlist = [word1 for word1 in p_stemmed if word1 in wordlist_uniq_words]

l_stemmed_in_wordlist = [word2 for word2 in l_stemmed if word2 in wordlist_uniq_words]
```

Comment: I have Completed it. Its working now.

Comment: k = 0
p_stemmed_diff = []
for w1 in lc_humor_uniq_words:
    for i in range(k,len(p_stemmed)):
        if len(w1) == len(p_stemmed[i]) and w1 != (p_stemmed[i]):
            p_stemmed_diff.append(w1)
        k = k + 1
        break
print(len(p_stemmed_diff))
l = 0
l_stemmed_diff = []
for w2 in lc_humor_uniq_words:
    for j in range(l,len(l_stemmed)):
        if len(w2) == len(l_stemmed[j]) and w2 != (l_stemmed[j]):
            l_stemmed_diff.append(w2)
        l = l + 1
        break
print(len(l_stemmed_diff))

Comment: Include that in the question as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58068992/revisions).  Or create an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use below code for step 14-17

```
p_stemmed_diff=[]
for w1,w2 in zip(lc_humor_uniq_words,p_stemmed):
    if len(w1) == len(w2) and w1 != w2:
        p_stemmed_diff.append(w1)
l_stemmed_diff=[]
for w1,w2 in zip(lc_humor_uniq_words,l_stemmed):
    if len(w1) == len(w2) and w1 != w2:
        l_stemmed_diff.append(w1)
print(len(p_stemmed_diff))
print(len(l_stemmed_diff))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. Also, I have used a different approach, it also worked and will share that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
lc_humor_uniq_words = list(lc_humor_uniq_words)
k = 0
p_stemmed_diff = []
for w1 in lc_humor_uniq_words:
   for i in range(k,len(p_stemmed)):
      if len(w1) == len(p_stemmed[i]) and w1 != (p_stemmed[i]):
         p_stemmed_diff.append(w1)
      k = k + 1
      break
print(len(p_stemmed_diff))


l = 0
l_stemmed_diff = []
for w2 in lc_humor_uniq_words:
   for j in range(l,len(l_stemmed)):
       if len(w2) == len(l_stemmed[j]) and w2 != (l_stemmed[j]):
          l_stemmed_diff.append(w2)
       l = l + 1
       break
print(len(l_stemmed_diff))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p_stemmed_diff=[w1 for w1,w2 in zip(lc_humor_uniq_words,p_stemmed) if len(w1) == len(w2) and w1 != w2]

l_stemmed_diff=[w1 for w1,w2 in zip(lc_humor_uniq_words,l_stemmed) if len(w1) == len(w2) and w1 != w2]
```

These One-liners can help in solving Steps 14-17, check this too.